# Есть ли разница, как прописывать опции компонента Vue?

Tags: vue.js

Интересует, есть ли практическая разница между

```
mounted() {
  this.method()
}
```

и

```
mounted: function() {
  this.method()
}
```

И внутри блока methods:

```
someMethod: function() {}
```

и

```
someMethod() {}
```

Comment: Никакой. Новый синтаксис, начиная с ES6, если я не ошибаюсь, позволяет определять свойство одним именем, если имя значения такое же, как и имя свойства.

Comment: Придерживаетесь ли вы какого-то кодстайла?

Comment: Нет, но в документации один способ написания, в реальных примерах - другой.